# What does it mean that a sequence of functions $f_n:G\to\mathbb{R}$ tends to infinity uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does it mean that for all $M>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $f_n(x)>M$ for all $n>N$ and for all $x\in G$?

Comment: Up to typo (should be $z\in G$) this is the definition.

Comment: Yeah you are right

Comment: Tend to pointwise infinity depends on z right? @abishankasaha

Comment: What is $z$? Do you mean $x$? $N$ will only depend $M$, not $x$, because the convergence is uniform.